# How to see the output of an old command?

Tags: konsole

I accidently run a program that printed 1.7GB of lines, making what was on the console, that is the result of some commands I launched, invisible.

I didn't close the terminal, is there a way to get back the output of these old commands ?

Comment: If it's in the buffer you should be able to scroll back up, if not, it's gone.

You can see what the commands were - using `history`

Answer (score 0):

Because you use term terminal instead of cmd, i assume you use linux. Linux always save commands you have executed in the file name .bash_history in your home folder. So you can see your command history by executing "cat .bash_history" or "nano .bash_history" or "vi .bash_history in your terminal.

Thanks